# A square matrix A is invertible if and only if det A ≠ 0. Use the theorem above to find all values of k for which A is invertible

Tags: matrices, inverse

$$\begin{pmatrix} k & k & 0 \\ k^2 & 25 & k^2 \\ 0 & k & k \end{pmatrix}?$$

I did a sample question before this one:

$$\begin{pmatrix} k & k & 0 \\ k^2 & 16 & k^2 \\ 0 & k & k \end{pmatrix}?$$

And was able to get k ≠ -2√2, 0, 2√2. Not sure exactly how, can anyone help me guide my way through these two questions?

Comment: As this is just a 3x3 matrix, you could just write out the determinant as a polynomial in $k$. Then find the roots of this polynomial.

Comment: Since a square matrix is invertible iff the determinant of A is not equal to $0$, then you simply find the determinant of A, (which you'll get, I think a cubic expression), equate that expression to zero and whatever values you get are the values that would not make A invertible.

Comment: start with $k\neq 0$.

Comment: Your second problem has the right answers. For the first, calculate the determinant, say going down the first column. We get $k(25k-k^3)-k^2(k^2)=25k^2-2k^4$. Setting this equal to $0$, we get $k=0$ or $k=\pm 5/\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the same thing you did before. First, take the determinant of 
$$\begin{pmatrix} k & k & 0 \\ k^2 & 25 & k^2 \\ 0 & k & k \end{pmatrix}$$
to obtain the equation $25k^2-2k^4$. So if this equation is zero, then the matrix is not invertible. Then
$$
\begin{align}
25k^2-2k^4&=0 \\
k^2(25-2k^2)&=0 \\
k^2(5+\sqrt{2}k)(5-\sqrt{2}k) &=0
\end{align}
$$
So $k=0,\frac{5}{\sqrt{2}}$ or $-\frac{5}{\sqrt{2}}$. Therefore, if $k$ is any real number except $0,\frac{5}{\sqrt{2}},-\frac{5}{\sqrt{2}}$ then the matrix is invertible.

Answer (score 0):

While the question is intended as an exercise in calculating the determinant of a matrix, note that one can also determine the answer by simple inspection (as one can do so in [a recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/565218/invertible-matrix-exercise)):

- When is there a column of zeros?
- When is the second column the sum of the first and the third columns?